# $F(t) := \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-itx}f(x)dx$ continuously differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f \in L^1([-1,1])$. I want to prove that

$$F(t) := \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-itx}f(x)dx$$

is continuously differentiable. I have absolutely no idea how to solve this. Any hints?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: if $f(x) \in L^1([-1,1])$ then $x f(x) \in  L^1([-1,1])$ too, so that $F'(t) = \int_{-1}^1 (-ix) e^{-itx}  f(x) dx$, where proving the last formula is a matter of $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of $F'(t) =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}$

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't it be $F'(t) = \int_{-1}^{1}(-ix)e^{-itx}f(x)dx$?